# Can't build a new android project in eclipse - folders are white and haven't got content

Tags: android, eclipse, project, building

When I click finish in the 'new android project' window  the window doesn't close itself. I have to close the window manually. When I'm looking at the new project the folders are white and the `src` folder haven't got the MainActivity that I have just created in the 'new android project' window. I reinstalled eclipse and the sdk stuff but it didn't help. In the project properties I click 'android' and eclipse says: `The currently displayed page contains invalid values.` I use Eclipse Indigo 4.2 and Android SDK Manager Revision 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes reinstalling Eclipse and Android SDK doens't work properly. When I started with it I got the same problem and fixed it by deleting Eclipse's folder AND the Android's folders created when I installed it (by default Android's folders can be found in  C:\ )

I deleted the folder 'Android' and '.android', only after that I downloaded again Eclipse and Android SDK. Try doing this and follow carefully the instructions to install the
[ADT Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Comment: thanks for this answer, but where can I find the .android folder on a mac?

Comment: I don't have a mac but I thing you can find it typping in your terminal the following code:
 "cd ~/.android"
and "open ."

Comment: the first project that I created was succefully created. But the second one has got the same error... EDIT: I think I got it. When I tick the box 'create custom launcher icon' it doesn't work, but when I don't tick the box, it works... it's strange.

Comment: I think it helped, exporting the project works now. (It didn't work before the reinstall.) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem.
You've already figured it out but I can confirm you are right.
So make sure that the `create custom launcher icon` is set to **false** in the wizard.
I'm using the latest Eclipse 3.7 with the latest Android.

Comment: Thanks.. This works. Not sure why this problem happens. Let us know if you find any solution of this issue. Thanks a ton..